# merge doesn't work for Custom time stamp type in JPA/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, merge

I have a custom time stamp class whihc contverts the time to UTC. In my entity class i do    use that custom type class for timstamp column. so that it will save the time in UTC.But during merge if this entity has updated value for this column, values in DB is not getting updated through merge.Seems like merge is not working for this custom defined timestamp type column.

```
  @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED", nullable = false)
   @Type(type="org.timeutil.HibernateUTC$TimestampType")
   private Date lastUpdated;

   en.merge(employee);
```

above merge operation doesn't update this value in DB if i have only this column to update for employee entity.

Comment: Please check generate SQL script or you can update here

Comment: thanks Please give little more info.